# How to tell systemd service to take user from configuration file?

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to make systemd service configurable like in the example below? I want to make **USER**, **GROUP** and **DIR** configurable in an extra file like /etc/default/service.

My target environment is a OpenSuse Linux 15.1. Systemd 234

```
[Unit]
Description=Sample Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=$USER
Group=$GROUP
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=$DIR
ExecStart=/opt/123/service.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/123/service.sh stop
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

PS: There is still the possibility to do in the service.sh doing config file parsing and issuing user specific things then. However I am wondering of a simple way directly.

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5501#issuecomment-283362610

Comment: @muru Thanks for the pointer. From this I learned this: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-drop-in-units.html

Answer (score 1):

## The systemd people do not like environment files.

`/etc/default/example` is of course an environment file in this scenario.

Several of the systemd people are on record, over the years, as saying that environment files are a mechanism that they should never have given to systemd in the first place.

The native systemd mechanism is, after all, the service unit file itself.  Customizing a service with administrator-defined or machine-specific stuff is, in their view, a matter of dropping in snippet `.conf` files for units, that add or replace keys in the main unit file.

Generating package-defined main service units with parameterized settings for users and whatnot is a matter of text processing and macro replacement to create the actual service unit from a template, as indeed many packages do.

> (But honestly, there's really no point in trying to dynamically convert stuff into a file that is suitable for `EnvironmentFile=`. *[…]* Also `/etc/sysconfig` is a Redhatism that should really go away, the whole concept is flawed. Adding a new `/run/sysconfig/` certainly makes that even worse.)
>
> I probably should never have added `EnvironmentFile=` in the first place. Packagers misunderstand that unit files are subject to admin configuration and should be treated as such, and that spliting out  configuration of unit files into separate `EnvironmentFiles=` is a really non-sensical game of unnecessary indirection.

— Lennart Poettering (2015-12-09). *[Query regarding "EnvironmentFile"](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2015-December/035236.html)*.  systemd-devel.

> Use of `EnvironmentFile=` is pretty much always a bad idea, and we probably should never have added that, since it invites packagers to reintroduce the `/etc/default/` and `/etc/sysconfig/` madness we try to remove.

— Lennart Poettering (2015-07-22). *[please consider having variables for an entire unit file](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/618#issuecomment-123808429)*. systemd bug #618.  GitHub.